# Why didn't I find an overloaded form with HWND type parameters for the ScreenToClient function in the afxwin. h file?

Tags: c++, mfc

Why didn't I find an overloaded form with HWND type parameters for the ScreenToClient function in the afxwin. h file? In the afxwin. h file, there are only two overloads related to ScreenToClient, one of which is of type LPPOINT and the other is of type LPRECT? How should I specify the parent control?

[image: code in afxwin.h]

Comment: Did you actually try to compile or do you trust IntelliSense? I can't see properly since you put a picture instead of text in your question. Please don't.

Comment: Because these are member functions of a [CWnd class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170), and the CWnd class IS your control and that has a HWND member. How much C++ have you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overloaded methods you are looking at are *non-static members* of the [`CWnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class) class. So, the `HWND` that belongs to whatever `CWnd`-drived object you call the methods on is the parent control that gets used.

It sounds like you are instead looking for the *standalone* Win32 API functions that are in `winuser.h` not `afxwin.h`.

Comment: thank you, according to you answer, I tried "ParentControl->ScreenToClient(&CRect)" and it worked successfully. if I use “ScreenToClient()” directly, it means "this->ScreenToClient()".

Comment: @shibayan Yes, in C++, non-static method calls from within an object have an implied `this->` object, along with an implied `this` parameter in the call itself.  Overloading can get you around that if there is a free function with the same name, or (I prefer) scoping the same-named free function to its namespace (so if global scope, I do `::ScreenToClient(hOther, &rOther.TopLeft()); ::ScreenToClient(hOther, &rOther.BottomRight());`) to remove any ambiguity (not just for the programmer, but tooltips, code analyzers, et.al.)